# Python: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

When executing the script below I get:

ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

I understand that this is because num is inside the first for loop and last_host is dependend of num but I have no idea how to work around this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import datetime as dt
import glob as glob
import os as os
import shutil as shutil
import signal as signal
import subprocess as sp
import sys as sys

# Open PDB file and read coordinates
pdb_file = open('align_z.pdb', 'r')
new_pdb_file = open('vac.pdb', 'w')



#Get last host atom
for num, line in enumerate(pdb_file, 1):
    if "L01" in line:
       print num
       break 


last_host=int(num)
print(last_host-1)

for atom in range(0, last_host-1):
    data = pdb_file.readline()
    new_pdb_file.write(data)
```

Comment: More Pythonic `last_host = next((num for num, line in enumerate(pdb_file, 1) if "L01" in line), len(list(pdb_file)))`. Saves you 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not get me the first line that contains L01 but the last one. I need to find the first line that says L01

Comment: No, it should work. In case you get the last one there is no line containing `"L01"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you iterate `pdf_file` by `enumerate` you cannot iterate it again except invoking `pdb_file.seek(0)` seek(0) changes the stream position to the beginning

Here's my modification:

```
num = 1
for line in pdb_file:
    num += 1
    if "L01" in line:
       print num
       break 

pdb_file.seek(0)  # go back to the beginning and then it can be iterated again

last_host=int(num)
print(last_host-1)

for atom in range(0, last_host-1):
    data = pdb_file.readline()
    new_pdb_file.write(data)
```

Comment: This worked well, thanks a lot! Can you explain what you mean with "num is out of scope"? I am completely new to python and not sure how it works in the first place...

Comment: @AndreasTosstorff it's my fault. I thought `num` is a local variable which is only visible in the for-loop block, here's a really good explanation https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2008-October/002109.html