# exceptions.ValueError Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to create tables from a directory containing multiple csvs using a script with psycopg2 and pandas so that the tables can be integrated into a postgreSQL database. The script should read the csvs in the folder, make pandas tables using pd.csv_read to get the column names, create a table, and then copy it's associated csv's values to it.

Here is my script thus far:

```
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
import os

conn = psy.connect("host=localhost dbname=somedb user=postgres password=somepw")
cur = conn.cursor()


# make a list of all the csvs to bring into pgAdmin
path = r"C:\Data\Waste_Intervention\Census_Tables\Cleaned"
fList = os.listdir(path)

# create tables in pandas to get column names for each table
# use these values to create tables with psycopg2
for doc in fList:
    pathCSV = "{}\\{}".format(path, doc)
    tableName = doc.split("_")[-1][:-4] # this strips the descriptive part of the file path
                                        # for the table name
    table = pd.read_csv(pathCSV)

    pgCols = [] # this will hold column names and data types
    types=["integer Primary Key"]
    cols = table.columns
    colsLen = len(table.columns)
    x = 1
    while x < colsLen:
        types.append("numeric")
        x += 1
    pgTups = zip(cols, types)
    pgCols.append(', '.join([str(lst[0]) + " " + str(lst[1]) for lst in pgTups]))
    # pgcols is now in the form column1 datatype, column2 2 datatype

    statement =  'CREATE TABLE ' + tableName + '(' + pgCols[0] + ')'
    # statement used in execute

    cur.execute(statement)

    # tale is created. now use same file in csv_read to copy data into table
    with open(pathCSV, 'r') as f:
        next(f)
        cur.copy_from(f, tableName, sep=',')
    conn.commit()
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
QueryCanceledError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-242-4d5401b7a834> in <module>()
     31     with open(pathCSV, 'r') as f:
     32         next(f)
---> 33         cur.copy_from(f, tableName, sep=',')
     34     conn.commit()
QueryCanceledError: COPY from stdin failed: error in .read() call: exceptions.ValueError Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data
CONTEXT:  COPY age, line 1
```

I tried using cur.seek(0) to reset the cursor as suggested here:[Python: ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42423210/python-valueerror-mixing-iteration-and-read-methods-would-lose-data)

but this throws an error that cursor object has no attribute 'seek'

Comment: you are not showing your import statements and are using dome libraries I am not familiar with;  It appears that copy_from reads from a file to load into a database.  This means that you don't need to read the file manually.  try deleting the line: next(f)

Comment: @AlanHoover will try that. added first bit of code with import statements and connection to database command.

Comment: @AlanHoover that got me closer but had to use copy_epert to make it work. Will be deleting post.